# Getting Uploadify working with Codeigniter - 302 HTTP error

Tags: codeigniter, uploadify

I'm having a bit of a headache trying to get Uploadify working with Codeigniter. Basically what i'm trying to do is upload multiple files and then run a db query to add it's details to my db. I am going to add more sophisticated code later (like getting EXIF/IPTC data), but for now I just need it to grab the filename and insert into the db for each photo after it's uploaded.

Trouble is i'm getting a HTTP 302 error. I've set this:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

And I also put the following in my .htaccess file:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

But it caused the entire site to stop working, throwing up an 'Internal server error'.

I really want uploadify to work, it's great, just a bit of a nightmare with Codeigniter!

My code is below:

Input in my view:

```
<input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileInput").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : '<?php echo base_url()?>assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : '<?php echo site_url()?>/upload/do_upload/',
            'cancelImg'      : '<?php echo base_url()?>assets/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg',
            'folder'         : 'assets/photos/highres',
            'auto'           : true,
            'multi'          : true,
            'onError'        : function (event,ID,fileObj,errorObj) {
                          alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
                        }
        });    });

    </script>
```

My controller:

```
public function do_upload()
        {
            // check for login, if logged in
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == "1")
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/photos/highres/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
                $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
                $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
                $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if(! $this->upload->do_upload('Filedata'))
                {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                   $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();

                   $upload_info = $this->upload->data();

                   // Insert file information into database
                   $data = array(
                                    'id' => NULL,
                                    'filename' => $upload_info['file_name']
                                );
                   $this->db->insert('photos', $data);
                  }
            } 
            else
            {
                // redirect to signin page if not logged in
                redirect('signin');
            }
        }
```

Any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

change files /application/config/mimes.php
add

```
'application/octet-stream'
```

on

```
'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'),
```

and finally the mimes like this

```
'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'application/octet-stream'),
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'application/octet-stream'),
'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'application/octet-stream'),
'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png', 'application/octet-stream'),
```